# Display UITableViewController in search mode

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

My application displays UITableViewController with search bar modally. What I'd like to do is displaying that view controller in search mode from the start so that user don't have to tap on the search bar. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

set `[searchBar becomeFirstResponder];`

Comment: give this code in viewDidLoad.                               @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;  connect searchBar to IB.